# Mac m1 macports installation failed

Tags: macos, macports

I tried installing macports in my mac but it has been stuck in the middle for like days and due to this my mac is not shutting down, please help me out with this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://superuser.com/help), especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)